# Seleccionar data-atributo dentro de SVG

Tags: javascript, html, html5, svg, data-atributos

Tengo el siguiente SVG *inline* dentro de mi página web:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-action="counter" class="button"
     width="320" height="90" viewBox="0 0 320 90">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="320" height="82" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#114477" />
  <text alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" 
        x="160" y="41" font-size="48" fill="#c1cedb">Botón</text> 
</svg>
```

Quiero que, no importa dónde pulse el usuario en el SVG, se lance una función que controle el evento y para eso tengo el siguiente JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(this.dataset.action);
});
```

El problema está en que parece que siempre me devuelve un error porque JavaScript dice que `dataset` no está definido para el elemento seleccionado:

```js
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(this.dataset.action);
});
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-action="counter" class="button"
     width="320" height="90" viewBox="0 0 320 90">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="320" height="82" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#114477" />
  <text x="160" y="41" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48" fill="#c1cedb">Botón</text> 
</svg>
```

El mismo código pero para otro elemento HTML (p.e. un `div`) funciona sin problemas. Traté de mover el atributo `data-action` al `rect` (cambiando el selector) pero recibo el mismo error. ¿Qué es lo que falla?¿Cómo puedo seleccionar un data-atributo en SVG desde JavaScript?

Comment: he probado el código que comentas y a mi me funciona perfectamente. Te dejo el enlace [aquí](http://codepen.io/BuiltByEdgar/pen/WxBymR?editors=1011)

Comment: @eledgaar ese codepen me da el siguiente error en la consola: "pen.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined" que es el mismo que recibo cuando ejecuto el código de arriba. Y me da el mismo fallo en Internet Explorer 11, Edge, Firefox y Chrome

Comment: El problema es que `dataset` es parte del spec de  [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) y tu estas usando un svg que sería un [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element). Algunas versiones de Chrome lo implementan pero eso no es parte del estandard. Está disponible en firefox a partir de la [version 51](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=921834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes razón, solo me funcionaba en (Mac) Safari Release 11 (Safari 9.1.2, WebKit 11603.1.2) pero en Chrome Versión 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) no.

Creo que la solución es utilizar [getAttributeNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/element/getAttributeNS), no lo he utilizado nunca pero seguro que la docu te aclara bastante las cosas.

```
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.getAttributeNS(null, 'data-action', null));
})
```

He editado el [ejemplo](http://codepen.io/BuiltByEdgar/pen/WxBymR?editors=1011) para que compruebes que funciona.

Comment: Genial. Esto es lo que buscaba y funciona perfecto.

Comment: Me alegra poder ayudarte 

Comment: Parece que no funciona en Firefox (aunque no importa en este caso), pero sí en IE, Edge y Chrome

Comment: En Firefox 46.0.1 me está funcionando. Asegurase de pasar el `event` a la función callback.

Comment: Estoy en Firefox 47.0.1 en el CodePen que compartiste y no me escribe anda en la consola. En los demás navegadores funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Que extraño... He actualizado a la 47.0.1 y a mi me funciona tanto en la consola de Firefox como en la de Codepen. (Estoy en un mac).